# Direct Query and Summarize workaround

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, summarize

I am having a hard time finding a way to summarize sevaral direct query tables based on some measures. What's really gets me is that, if I create the summarized table (either with SUMMARIZE() or SUMMARIZECOLUMNS()) and then publish it, it actually works in the PBI Service. The problem comes when I try to open the .pbix file or download it from the service to make additional changes - Something went wrong: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Assuming that's because DQ is not compatible with summarize.

My tables have completely different columns and measures based on various rates/dates.

```
Consolidated = 
VAR LocationX = SUMMARIZE(Date,
    Date[Calendar Year], Date[Calendar Month],,
    "Revenue",[Total Revenue (LocationX)],
    "Gross Profit",[Gross Profit (LocationX)],
    "Efficiency",[Efficiency (LocationX)])

VAR LocationY = SUMMARIZE(Date,
    Date[Calendar Year], Date[Calendar Month],,
    "Revenue",[Total Revenue (LocationY)],
    "Gross Profit",[Gross Profit (LocationY)],
    "Efficiency",[Efficiency (LocationY)])
RETURN  
    UNION(LocationX, 
    LocationY)
```

How can I get around this without switching the tables to Import mode. I've looked into defining table views to use as aggregates but I'm not sure that's going to help or I cannot fully understand it. There has to be a way to do something about this. What would you guys suggest?

Comment: Are you sure it's not a permissions problem? Can you verify that direct query works in these cases without the SUMMARIZE code?

Comment: Hey @AlexisOlson, Thanks for chiming in. Yes, I am 100% positive. Without the SUMMARIZE table, the report works after you save it and open it again. I've tried with SUMMARIZECOLUMN and as soon as I add that to the model, save it, try to open it again => problem. I'm also an admin on the SQL Server so the issue is absolutely on the Power BI Side.